# Send multiple data to socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a few clients trying to connect to a java program using a socket, so when two connections arrives at the same time one of them are not received the response, I read in many posts that there is a problem when the server  send the response at the same time to many clients so I try to make a synchronized block of that response but it doesn't work

I create a ServerSocket, wait until a connection is made and create a thread

```
public class Server{

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    static int PORT = 8080;
    public static void main(String [] args){
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            while(true){
                ServerThread obj=new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept());
                Thread thread =new Thread(obj);  
                thread.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On the thread I read the input that the client is sending,  decrypt that input, process it, encrypt the response and send that response to the client

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread{

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class);

    private Aes aes;
    static int SIZE=500;
    static int TIMEOUT=10000;
    private Socket s;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public ServerThread(Socket s) {
        this.s=s;
    }

    public void run() {
        try{
            System.out.println(this.getName());
            System.out.println("Just connected to " + s.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            s.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT);
            int equis = 0;
            StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();

            while((equis=in.readByte())>0){
                builder.append(Character.toChars(equis));
            }
            String valor=builder.toString();
            System.out.println(valor);
            valor=Encriptacion("decrypt", valor);
            System.out.println(valor);
            String[] datos = valor.split("\\|");

            String tarjeta=datos[0];
            double monto=(Double.parseDouble(datos[1].isEmpty()?"0":datos[1]))/100;
            int tipoTransaccion=Integer.parseInt(datos[2].isEmpty()?"0":datos[2]);
            String numeroSerieTPV=datos[3];
            String usuario=datos[4];
            String contrasena=datos[5];
            String llave=datos[6];
            String referencia=datos[7];
            String referencia2=datos[8];
            int plazo=Integer.parseInt(datos[9].isEmpty()?"0":datos[9]);
            int cvv=Integer.parseInt(datos[10].isEmpty()?"0":datos[10]);
            int cvv2=Integer.parseInt(datos[11].isEmpty()?"0":datos[11]);
            int transaccionId=Integer.parseInt(datos[12].isEmpty()?"0":datos[12]);
            int comercioId=Integer.parseInt(datos[13].isEmpty()?"0":datos[13]);
            int terminalId=Integer.parseInt(datos[14].isEmpty()?"0":datos[14].trim());

            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
            buf.append("");
            Transacciones transacciones=new Transacciones();
            if(tipoTransaccion==1){
                transacciones.compra(tarjeta, monto, comercioId, plazo, terminalId,llave);
            }else if(tipoTransaccion==2){
                transacciones.pago(tarjeta, monto, comercioId, terminalId,llave);
            }else if(tipoTransaccion==3){
                transacciones.disposicion(tarjeta, monto,comercioId, plazo, terminalId,llave);
            }else if(tipoTransaccion==4){
                transacciones.reporte(comercioId, terminalId,llave);
            }else if(tipoTransaccion==5){
                transacciones.validarUsuario(usuario, contrasena, numeroSerieTPV);
            }else if(tipoTransaccion==6){
                transacciones.confirmacion(transaccionId);
                return;
            }else{
                transacciones.getEnvioDatos().setCodigoError("0");
                transacciones.getEnvioDatos().setDescripcionError("Tipo de transaccion invalido.");
            }
            buf.append(transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getCodigoError()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getDescripcionError()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getFecha()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getHora()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getNombreCliente()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getClave()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getPromesas()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getReporte()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getLlave()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getTerminalBloqueada()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getTerminalEstatus()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getTerminalId()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getComercioId()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getTerminalNombre()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getSucursalId()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getNombresucursal()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getDireccionSucursal()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getPermisoCompra()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getPermisoDisposicion()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getPermisoPago()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getPermisoTiempoAire()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getCompraMinima()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getDisposicionMinima()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getDisposicionMaxima()+"|"
                    +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getPlazos()+"|");
            if(buf.length()<SIZE) {
                while(buf.length()<SIZE)
                    buf.append("*");
            }
            String str=buf.toString();
            System.out.println(str);
            String x=Encriptacion("encrypt", str);
            System.out.println(this.getName());
            System.out.println("Just connected to " + s.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            DataOutputStream out=null;
            synchronized(this){
                out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());                
                out.write(x.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")), 0, x.length());
                System.out.println(x);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
            s.close;
            in.close();
        } catch(SocketTimeoutException e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        } catch(IOException e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }catch(Throwable e){

            System.out.println(e);
        }finally{

        }
    }
}
```

I read a lot of web pages but I can't find an answer, Could someone help me to find my error?,

Thanks in advance

**Edited:**

I change my code :

```
public class Server{

    public static void main(String [] args){
        ServerThread obj=new ServerThread();
    }
}

public class ServerThread {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class);

    static int SIZE=500;
    static int TIMEOUT=10000;
    private Socket s;
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    static int PORT = 8080;
    private Object lock=new Object();

    public ServerThread() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
        try {
            Thread accept = new Thread() {
                public void run(){
                    try {
                        s=serverSocket.accept();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(this.getName());
                process();
            }};
            accept.start();
            accept.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}

public void process(){
    try{
        System.out.println("Just connected to " + s.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        s.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT);
        int equis = 0;
        StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();

        while((equis=in.readByte())>0){
            builder.append(Character.toChars(equis));
        }
        String valor=builder.toString();
        System.out.println(valor);
        valor=encriptacion("decrypt", valor);

        System.out.println(valor);
        String[] datos = valor.split("\\|");

        String tarjeta=datos[0];
        double monto=(Double.parseDouble(datos[1].isEmpty()?"0":datos[1]))/100;
        int tipoTransaccion=Integer.parseInt(datos[2].isEmpty()?"0":datos[2]);
        String numeroSerieTPV=datos[3];
        String usuario=datos[4];
        String contrasena=datos[5];
        String llave=datos[6];
        String referencia=datos[7];
        String referencia2=datos[8];
        int plazo=Integer.parseInt(datos[9].isEmpty()?"0":datos[9]);
        int cvv=Integer.parseInt(datos[10].isEmpty()?"0":datos[10]);
        int cvv2=Integer.parseInt(datos[11].isEmpty()?"0":datos[11]);
        int transaccionId=Integer.parseInt(datos[12].isEmpty()?"0":datos[12]);
        int comercioId=Integer.parseInt(datos[13].isEmpty()?"0":datos[13]);
        int terminalId=Integer.parseInt(datos[14].isEmpty()?"0":datos[14].trim());

        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        buf.append("");
        Transacciones transacciones=new Transacciones();
        if(tipoTransaccion==1){
            transacciones.compra(tarjeta, monto, comercioId, plazo, terminalId,llave);
        }else if(tipoTransaccion==2){
            transacciones.pago(tarjeta, monto, comercioId, terminalId,llave);
        }else if(tipoTransaccion==3){
            transacciones.disposicion(tarjeta, monto,comercioId, plazo, terminalId,llave);
        }else if(tipoTransaccion==4){
            transacciones.reporte(comercioId, terminalId,llave);
        }else if(tipoTransaccion==5){
            transacciones.validarUsuario(usuario, contrasena, numeroSerieTPV);
        }else if(tipoTransaccion==6){
            transacciones.confirmacion(transaccionId);
            return;
        }else{
            transacciones.getEnvioDatos().setCodigoError("0");
            transacciones.getEnvioDatos().setDescripcionError("Tipo de transaccion invalido.");
        }
        buf.append(transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getCodigoError()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getDescripcionError()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getFecha()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getHora()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getNombreCliente()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getClave()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getPromesas()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getReporte()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getLlave()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getTerminalBloqueada()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getTerminalEstatus()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getTerminalId()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getComercioId()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getTerminalNombre()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getSucursalId()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getNombresucursal()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getDireccionSucursal()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getPermisoCompra()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getPermisoDisposicion()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getPermisoPago()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getPermisoTiempoAire()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getCompraMinima()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getDisposicionMinima()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getDisposicionMaxima()+"|"
                +transacciones.getEnvioDatos().getPlazos()+"|");
        if(buf.length()<SIZE) {
            while(buf.length()<SIZE)
                buf.append("*");
        }
        String str=buf.toString();
        System.out.println(str);
        String x=encriptacion("encrypt", str);
        System.out.println("Just connected to " + s.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        envio(x);
        in.close();
    } catch(SocketTimeoutException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Throwable e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{

    }

}

public void envio(String x){
    synchronized(lock){
        DataOutputStream out=null;
        try {
            out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            out.write(x.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")), 0, x.length());
            System.out.println(x);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
    }
}
}
```

But I still have issues when sending the response to the clients, the synchronized doesn't work, what am I doing wrong??

thanks again

Comment: your ServerThread is already extending Thread. Why do you create another Thread instance? Why not just do `obj.start()`?

Comment: There is no problem with multiple threads writing on different sockets concurrently.  Besides, your `synchronize(this)`  has no effect -- there is a separate `ServerThread` object created for each connection (which is a good thing) so multiple threads have their own locks, effectively there will never be any wait for acquiring the lock. What is the exact problem you are facing? Try to put a breakpoint in the `run` method and step through it. For posting here, it would be best to reduce your code to smallest sample that demonstrates the problem, currently there is a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: And with reference to @Serge's comment, it would be better for `ServerThread` to `extend Runnable` instead of `Thread`.

Comment: @MiserableVariable, how can I make that part of code to wait until the send of data is finished or there is a different way to send data to the clients??, what is the difference of extends runnable and extends thread?

Comment: You could synchronize on something that all objects share, e.g. `ServerThread.class`. But more importantly *synchronization is not required*.

Comment: For a test, why don't you remove all processing and instead send back a simple string, say `"Just connected to " + s.getRemoteSocketAddress()` which will let you verify that different clients are getting unique response.

Comment: What is `Encriptacion`? It is named like a `class` but it seems to be a `method`. Perhaps it is not thread-safe and requires synchronization? If the test with sending back simple string works, you can build on it slowly to get to where you want to be.

Comment: not really Encriptacion encrypt the string input and return the encrypt string to later send it to the client

Comment: So it's a method? It should be named `encriptacion`. Also, do try a simpler example first.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing comments:

There is no problem with multiple threads writing on different sockets concurrently. Besides, your `synchronize(this)` has no effect -- there is a separate ServerThread object created for each connection (which is a good thing) so multiple threads have their own locks, effectively there will never be any wait for acquiring the lock. What is the exact problem you are facing? Try to put a breakpoint in the run method and step through it.

What is Encriptacion? Perhaps it is not thread-safe and requires synchronization? If the test a sending back simple string works, you can build on it slowly to get to where you want to be. You could for example, read all of input and respond with a string such as `"Just connected to " + s.getRemoteSocketAddress()` which will help you verify that the multi-threading is working while also seeing different response from different concurrent connections.

From there, you could take small steps -- I would first add decrypting the request payload and writing it back in response (sort of echo server).

Comment: I have 3 POS trying to connect to my server socket, the connection to that server is ok, but when I try to send the message to those POS at least one of them is not received the response (I noticed it happen when two or more connections are made it at the same time), as I have this POS, my java program needs to run in a server where I can't debug it so is a little complicated to find my error, I see some tutorials that say that the way to synchronize a part of block is to make a join of that thread and later add the word synchronized in the method but it didn't work

Comment: There are thousands of apps deployed in the internet that serve millions of concurrent users. Surely you don't think they write to one connection at a time? Take StackOveflow for example, do you think it only refreshes page one user at a time? Your problem is definitely elsewhere and the solution is most definitely not to write back on one connection at a time.